# Jquery works in Safari but not in Firefox 11

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I had a js file that works fine as

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".btn-save").click( function() {
        var1 = $("#var1").val();
        var2 = $("#var2").val();
        var3 = $("#var3").val();
        var4 = $("#var4").val();
        var5 = $("#var5").val();

        $.post("json.test.php",
            {
                "var1" : var1,
                "var2" : var2,
                "var3" : var3,
                "var4" : var4,
                "var5" : var5
            },
            function(data)
            {
                if(data.type == "success") {
                    if(data.data == "saved") {
                     ...
                   }
                    self.close();
                }
                if(data.type == "error") {
                    alert("Error: " + data.message);
                }
            },
            "json"
        );

    });
});
```

It works fine, and script json.test.php receive all 5 variables as

```
@$var_php = $_POST["var1"];
```

Now , I added another field to the form and I just add to javascript js program

```
var6 = $("#var6").val();
```

and posted as

```
"var5" : var5
```

After I did those changes, in Safari the program json.test.php receives all 6 variables ok, but in Firefox 11 only receives the first 5 variables with the right values, but for var6 always receives a Null .

Do you know why is working ok in Safari and not in Firefox 11. Also why in Firefox 11 is working fine for the first 5 variables but not if I add more?

Comment: I suppose, that problem lies in exact HTML. Dynammically added input may have `id` and don't have `name` or something like this.

Comment: I tried also with var6 = $("#var6").text()

Comment: The form field looks like:                                            <input type="text" id="var6" name="var6" size="1" maxlength="1">

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to regenerate the error in Firefox 11 but serialising form values may be a workaround for you. At least it's a much better approach when you're dealing with form inputs.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevents refreshing page on form submit
    $.post("test.php", $("#myform").serialize(),
       function(data) {
          $('#target').html(data);
       });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="var1" name="var1" size="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" id="var2" name="var2" size="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" id="var3" name="var3" size="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" id="var4" name="var4" size="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" id="var5" name="var5" size="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" id="var6" name="var6" size="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="target">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And test.php:

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
   echo $_POST["var".$i];
} 
?>
```